# Curl of a Magnetic Field Produced by a Surface of Current

Tags: magnetostatics

If the curl of the magnetic field, produced by a volume of current, $J$, should be given by $ \nabla \times B = \mu_0 J$, then should the curl of a such field, produced by a surface of current, $K$, be given by $ \nabla \times B = \mu_0 K$ (or should it be instead given by a delta-function: zero every where and $\infty$ only at the surface itself)?

Answer (score 0):

it would still be $J$ but $J$ would.be 2 dimensional

If you want to keep it "3 dimensional" it could.be expressed as a delta function if you wish. perhaps if your current only exists on the $x,y$ plane and.not on the $z$ plane it would be
$$
J = j(x,y)\delta(z)
$$
(assuming current is located when $z =0$)

so that when  $z$ isn't 0 $j=0$ and when it is zero its infinite but its integral would be defined when solving for the fields

e.g
$$
\int j(x,y)\delta(z) dx dy dz
$$
is just
$$
\int \delta(z)dz  \int  j(x,y) dx dy
$$
now it's just $1 \times  \int  j(x,y) dS$
and we're back into 2 dimensions

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be correct just plugging $\vec{K}$ where previously there was a $\vec{J}$ (Notice the dimensions are not the same). If you're dealing with surface currents instead of volume currents, just apply the fact that
$$
\vec{J}=\frac{d\vec{K}}{dl_\perp}
$$
Where $dl_\perp$ is the direction perpendicular to the surface. In a clearer way, reverting the curl into a line integral with Stoke's theorem
$$
\oint{\vec{B}·d\vec{r}}=\mu_0\int{\vec{J}·d\vec{s}}=\mu_0\int{\vec{K}·d\vec{l}}
$$
Here $\vec{B}$ is to be integrated along the desired contour and $\vec{K}$ along the perpendicular direction to the current (but contained in the surface)